# Responsive canvas breakpoint for iphone

Tags: javascript, if-statement, canvas

I'm trying to add an if statement so I can change the canvas height when the window width is smaller than 750px.

This is what the current code looks like:

```
  function ResizeCanvas(e) {
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
                canvas.height = height;          
  }
```

Anyone how knows how to add if/else without breaking the code?

Answer (score 0):

```
function ResizeCanvas(e) {
      if(window.innerWidth<750){
                canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
                canvas.height = new_height;    
      }else{
                canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
                canvas.height = height;    
      }

}
```

Maybe  this :) but this was too easy question :) use google sometimes

Comment: thanks Marko! New to javascript! Will google some more next time :)